# It keeps giving me syntax error , unexpected token "if"

Tags: php

```
Require "header.Php"

if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'POST'){

    $username=addslashes($_POST['username']);

    $email=addslashes($_POST['email']);

    $password=addslashes($_POST['password']);

}
```

Comment: add ";" after your Require "header.Php" => Require "header.Php";

Comment: additionally, parentheses around a var does nothing and addslashes just mangles the input

Answer (score 0):

You don't have semicolon after Require "header.Php".
It should be:

```
Require "header.Php";
```

Comment: You wouldn't normally answer questions which are solved by typos like this.